# netcat inside a while read loop returning immediately

Tags: bash, shell

I am making a menu for myself, because sometimes I need to search (Or NMAP which port).
I want to do the same as running the command in the command line.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
nmap $1 | grep open | while read line; do
    serviceport=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1 | cut -d'/' -f1);
    if [ $i -eq $choice ]; then
        echo "Running command: netcat $1 $serviceport";
        netcat $1 $serviceport;
    fi;
    i=$(($i+1));
done;
```

It is closing immediately after it scanned everything with nmap.

Comment: Please run this through http://shellcheck.net/ for pointers on some of the other things that could stand to be fixed beyond the bug that led to the question directly.

Comment: ...also, nmap has an optional output format designed to be conducive to manipulation with shell tools; please consider using it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use FD 0 (stdin) for both your read loop and netcat. If you don't distinguish these streams, `netcat` can consume content emitted by the `nmap | grep` pipeline rather than leaving that content to be read by `read`.

This has a few undesirable effects: Further parts of the while/read loop don't get executed, and `netcat` sees a closed stdin stream and exits when the pipeline's contents are consumed (so you don't get interactive control of netcat, if that's what you're trying to accomplish). An easy way to work around this issue is to feed the output of your nmap pipeline in on a non-default file descriptor; below, I'm using FD 3.

There's a lot wrong with this code beyond the scope of the question, so please don't consider the parts I've copied-and-pasted an endorsement, but:

```
while read -r -u 3 line; do
    serviceport=${line%% *}; serviceport=${serviceport##/*}
    if [ "$i" -eq "$choice" ]; then
        echo "Running command: netcat $1 $serviceport"
        netcat "$1" "$serviceport"
    fi
done 3< <(nmap "$1" | grep open)
```